# Problem setting the page header in angular

Tags: angular

I have a page in app.component.html something like this,

```
<div class="sidenav">
  <img src="../../../assets/images/control-hub-white.svg">
  <a  (click)="onClickHandler('Clusters')" style="color:#05a1bf" > Link1 </a>
  <a  (click)="onClickHandler('Checks')" >Link2</a>
  <a href="/test3">Test3</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<h1> {{ heading }} </h1>
```

I have an onClickHandler in app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit {
 heading = 'default heading';
  ............
 onClickHandler(heading: string){
    this.heading = heading;
    alert(heading);
}
```

Here when I click on the link (clusters) I am getting an alert as expected 
like Clusters, Checks. But when the new page comes after clicking the link, I m getting the heading as default heading.

Can anybody tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: You are setting heading in AppComponent and when you go to new page, heading variable of AppComponent does not get new value. So it will always shows "default heading."
You can use service for updating header variable of AppComponent.

Comment: How are you going to the new page? I suspect you're not using routerLink, which then means the page is reloaded and always set to default.

Comment: Thanks @Zlatko. I had missed that.

Answer (score 0):

When you coming back to to this page again, The app.component get initiated again. So, again you will get the "default heading" only. For retaining you last heading please use services.

register your service in providers of app.module.ts

**app.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AppService { 
   heading: string = 'default heading';
}
```

**app.components.ts**

```
import {AppServices} from './app.service';

export class AppComponent  implements OnInit {

    constructor(private appService: AppService){}

    heading: string;

    onInint() {
       this.heading = this.appService.heading;
    }

    onClickHandler(heading: string){
        this.appService.heading = heading;
        alert(heading);
    }
}
```